# #ParseServer #OneSignal #ScheduledPush #ParseServerOneSignalPushAdapter

Tags: push-notification, parse-server, onesignal

**Issue Description**

We are using OneSignal as 3rd party push service and configured it using parse-server-onesignal-push-adapter as we are sending pushes from cloud code. Normal pushes are working but scheduled pushes are not. No matter what we set to "push_time" parameter on Push.send(), pushes are sent immediately.

**Expected Results**

Working scheduled pushes

**Actual Outcome**

Pushes are sent immediately even if there is push_time parameter set on Parse.Push.send().

**How we send pushes**

```
Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
        "alert": "Voting complete. Click here to see the results.",
        "sound": "cheering.caf",
        //"badge": "Increment",
        "content-available": 1,
        "category": "VOTING_COMPLETE",
        "qc": request.object.id
        },
        push_time: pushTime
    }, {
        success: function() {
            console.log('##### PUSH OK');
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log('##### PUSH ERROR');
        },
        useMasterKey: true
    });
```

**Environment Setup**

```
var express = require('express');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI ||        process.env.MONGODB_URI;

if (!databaseUri) {
    console.log('DATABASE_URI not specified, falling back to localhost.');
}

var OneSignalPushAdapter = require('parse-server-onesignal-push-adapter');
var oneSignalPushAdapter = new OneSignalPushAdapter({
    oneSignalAppId:"***************************",
    oneSignalApiKey:"***************************"
});

var api = new ParseServer({
    databaseURI: databaseUri || 'mongodb://localhost:27017/dev',
    cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
    appId: process.env.APP_ID || 'myAppId',
    masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY || '', 
    fileKey: process.env.FILE_KEY || '******************************', 
    serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL || 'http://localhost:1337/parse',

    verifyUserEmails: true,

    emailVerifyTokenValidityDuration: 2 * 60 * 60,

    preventLoginWithUnverifiedEmail: true,

    publicServerURL: 'http://***************************/parse',
    enableAnonymousUsers: false,
    revokeSessionOnPasswordReset: true,
    appName: '************************',
    emailAdapter: {
        module: 'parse-server-simple-mailgun-adapter',
        options: {
            fromAddress: 'no-reply@***************************.com',

            domain: 'mg.******************************.com',

            apiKey: 'key-******************************',
        }
    },
    oauth: {
    twitter: {
        consumer_key: "***************************", 
        consumer_secret: "***************************"
    }
},
push: {
    adapter: oneSignalPushAdapter
}
});

var app = express();

app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.status(200).send('Make sure to star the parse-server repo on     GitHub!');
});

app.get('/test', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public/test.html'));
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});

ParseServer.createLiveQueryServer(httpServer);
```

Answer (score 0):

the reason is because scheduling of push messages is not supported (yet) by parse server. Only parse.com currently supports it.

You can read about it in [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/wiki/Push)

If you really need this feature i suggest you to try to schedule a job in cloud code that will do it for you. Since scheduling jobs is also not supported out of the box you can find temporary solution in [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/pull/398)

Comment: We don't use Parse servers basic push service and its push adapter... Instead we use OneSignal and parse-server-onesignal-push-adapter. OneSignal supports scheduled pushes.

Comment: So i guess there is an issue with the one signal push adapter.. did you open an issue ? https://github.com/parse-server-modules/parse-server-onesignal-push-adapter/

Comment: Yes but no one replied